# Issue with the print command in Python 3.5

Tags: python, syntax-error

The code that I'm using on Python 3.5 is as follows,

```
sleep = int(input("How many hours do you sleep per night? "))

days = int(input("How many days do you sleep? ")

print("You sleep roughly " + sleep*str(days) + " per week
```

Unfortunately, it comes with the syntax error that my print command is not correct. I know that the brackets are required but it still is saying that something is not correct. The syntax error points to the "print" command and is confusing me a lot. I am relatively new to programming using Python and as such, this might be a beginner mistake but I have not been able to find anything related to this on stackoverflow as of yet.

Also, I am using Mac OS X so I am not sure if it is because of this or otherwise.

Comment: try this `str(sleep*days)` , you should cast multiple result to string.

Comment: Close your parentheses.

Comment: You're multiplying a string by an integer. If I sleep 8 hours per night and sleep 4 days (BTW, what does "How many days do sleep?" means?), it will print `"44444444"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sleep = int(input("How many hours do you sleep per night? "))

days = int(input("How many days do you sleep? "))

print("You sleep roughly " + str(sleep*days) + " per week")
```

You were missing a parenthesis at the end, and the casting was also incorrect.

As a more convenient method, try one of the different [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html):

```
print("You sleep roughly %s per week" % sleep*days)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that you have missed ')' at the end of one of your lines:

```
sleep = int(input("How many hours do you sleep per night? "))

days = int(input("How many days do you sleep? "))

print("You sleep roughly " + sleep*str(days) + " per week
```

Comment: Which line? What does this answer add that the others didn't?